# Detecting ruby binary compilation layout in runtime

Tags: ruby, binary, openssl

Quite often Ruby installed with RVM (the 'most popular tool to install Ruby') produces a binary not capable of SSL operations (like connecting via HTTPS). It's a known issue with a [known workaround](http://beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/).

If you're trying to use SSL with such Ruby binary it results in exception `LoadError: cannot load such file -- openssl`.

**Question**: is there any way I can tell which libs Ruby binary was built against and thus detect if it is capable of SSL or not **at runtime**? Other than trying to actually use SSL and catching the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you want to do the same work that require does, I think the easiest is to try to require openssl and rescue the LoadError in case it's not present on the system to detect its availability.

It seems to be an idiom [commonly](https://github.com/search?q=language%3A+ruby+require+%27openssl%27+rescue+LoadError&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=) used.

If you wanted something that detects afterwards if it was loaded or not would

```
ruby -ropenssl -e 'p defined? OpenSSL' # => "constant"
```

vs.

```
ruby -e 'p defined? OpenSSL' # => nil
```

help you?

That is, checking whether the return value of `defined?(OpenSSL)` is non-nil?

We commonly use this in [tests](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/test/openssl/test_pkey_ec.rb#L3) to exclude tests at runtime where features that are not available to all versions of OpenSSL are used, and to exclude tests completely (`if defined? OpenSSL`) if OpenSSL is not present as an extension.

Comment: that would make me start a separate process from my ruby code, but it's still probably better than relying on exception, will accept if there's no other answer

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, no, you can of course use `defined? OpenSSL` directly in your code, no need to fork it out into a separate process - I just used that as an example because you can conveniently type it into your terminal. If you look at the linked test, that's how it would look like inline.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. So I've got two ruby binaries - with and without SSL support. I'm creating a single line program `p defined? OpenSSL` and both ruby produce the same result b/c it's not defined until you require 'openssl'... and when I do require the one without SSL support gives an exception

Comment: Ah, OK I understand now. Yes, unless you want to do the same work that `require` does, I think the easiest is to try to `require openssl` and  rescue the LoadError in case it's not present on the system to detect its availability. I was confused, I thought you wanted something that detects *afterwards* if it was loaded or not. But without trying to require, the only option I see right now would be to traverse the `$LOAD_PATH` manually, looking for example for 'openssl.so'...

Comment: Ok, if you're saying that relying on exception is ok then I'm going to do it this way

Comment: Yes, seems to be an idiom [commonly](https://github.com/search?q=language%3A+ruby+require+%27openssl%27+rescue+LoadError&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=) used.